# Process textfile without delimter in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, text-files, rdd

I have text file which is big in size(3 GB) and want to process this text file in spark. There is no delimiter in this text file. After every 50th character new record starts but there is no delimiter between the records. I'm not getting any idea on how to load this data and process this file?

**sample.txt**

*thisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdata***thisisnewdatasetthisisnewdatasetthisisnewdatasetaa***thisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdata***thisisnewdatasetthisisnewdatasetthisisnewdatasetaa***thisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdata*

```
sc.textFile('path/to/file.txt') # this not helping here as there is no delimiter between records
```

Just to make recognize the pattern I used emphasis and strong, however as we know text file doesn't have any emphasis and strong, it's plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to use **`udf`** for this case, As **`regexp_extract_all`** not available until **Spark-3.1** version

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#read the file as csv
df=spark.read.csv("<file_path>").toDF("val")

#udf to capture 50 character groups
def regex_all_matches(s):
    all_matches = re.findall(r'.{1,50}', s)
    return all_matches

#register udf and 
regex_all_matches_udf = udf(regex_all_matches, ArrayType(StringType()))

df2 = df.withColumn('val', explode(regex_all_matches_udf(col('val'))))

#+--------------------------------------------------+
#|val                                               |
#+--------------------------------------------------+
#|thisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdata|
#|thisisnewdatasetthisisnewdatasetthisisnewdatasetaa|
#|thisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdata|
#|thisisnewdatasetthisisnewdatasetthisisnewdatasetaa|
#|thisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdatathisisdata|
#+--------------------------------------------------+
```